# Is patent US 4,734,658 A avalible free of change in commercial products?

Tags: international, licensing, expired-patent, us4734658

In reference to the patent: [US 4,734,658 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US4734658)

We are from India, we wish to use this patent in one of our products. Can we use this patent free of charge or we have to pay some amount?

Comment: Patent already expired if no overlapping patents are on said product public is open to use it.